# React Native Phone-based login

Tags: parse-platform, authentication, reactjs, react-native

Are there any good resources for having Phone-based login for React Native?

I came across the blog post below which was using Parse + Twilio. Has anyone implemented this for React Native or worked with a similar solution?

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/phone-based-login-can-you-dig-it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

1) parse is being deprecated, so don't bet on using that. See https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App

2) It seems like this is less about React-native and more about communicating with an API. All you'd need to do in React-native is send some data back and forth between a server based on tokens sent and verified on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at react-native-digits https://github.com/fixt/react-native-digits. It is a port of Twitter's phone-based login digits. I've not used it personally though